# AWS lambda Java - get env variable with multiple values

Tags: aws-lambda

I need to get a list with multiple values from an env variable. Something like this:

```
List:
    Field1: Value 1
    Field2: Value 2
    Field3: Value 3
```

I'm thinking of defining an env variable with a value like this:

```
MY_ENV_VAR = 1:3:43,5:7:9,9:65:12
```

And then parse it in Java:

```
class ParseObject {
   Integer field1;
   Integer field2;
   Integer field3;
}

List<ParseObject> parseObjects;
parseObjects[0].getField1(); // 1
parseObjects[0].getField2(); // 3
parseObjects[0].getField3(); // 43 

parseObjects[1].getField1(); // 5
parseObjects[1].getField2(); // 7
parseObjects[1].getField3(); // 9

parseObjects[2].getField1(); // 9
parseObjects[2].getField2(); // 65
parseObjects[2].getField3(); // 12
```

The way to parse this, would be with a regular expression. Do you like this approach? Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Env variables are meant for *configuration*: things that specify how execution is done, e.g. input/output locations, default language settings, etc. They're *not* great for data: things that might be arbitrarily sized are not ideal for env variables - even to the extent of the question you must ask: *"what's the max length of an env string?"*

In your code above, `MY_ENV_VAR = 1:3:43,5:7:9,9:65:12` *looks* like data. I would seriously consider whether this is the case. If it is, consider passing it as a function parameter when you invoke your lambda. If that doesn't work, you could also write the value `1:3:43,5:7:9,9:65:12` to a file in S3, and pass the *location* of that file as an env variable.

**If** the variable is in fact configuration, and it's always a list of three things, each containing three numbers, I would at the very least separate it into three different env variables, each with a descriptive name (even if it's just 1, 2, etc.), so that you don't have a single, nested env variable.